# jQueryUI Modal open event & MVC.NET causing error ".dialog is not a function"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, dialog

I hope someone can help as I'm at my wits end with this. What I'm trying to do is this.

1. "Draggable" Item is Dropped into a "Droppable" area (this works)
2. This posts the id of the item to my controller which returns the type of item it is (this works)
3. I pass the returned item name to a function which opens a modal and renders a partial view in the modal depending on the particular item.

The last bit is where the issue is. All the steps above work fine, the modal is popped and the partial view is rendered to the modal. But the button to close the dialog throws the error ".dialog is not a function" and after closing the modal using the 'x' in the corner subsequent attempts to open the modal will not work throwing a similar error.

Here's the example I'm working with to try get this working.

```
$(function () {
        $('.draggable').draggable({ containment: '#imageboundry', revert: 'valid' });
        $('#droppable').droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Home/AddToCart/' + $(ui.draggable).attr("id"),
                    success: function (data) {
                        getItemType(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function getItemType(itemName) {
        $('#dialogs').dialog({
            open: function () {
                $(this).load("AdditionalContent", { itemName: itemName }, function () {
                    alert("This happened");
                });
            },
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: itemName,
            width: 400,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my controller which returns the partial view to the modal

```
public PartialViewResult AdditionalContent(string itemName)
    {

        return PartialView("_" + itemName + "Attributes");
    }
```

The close button works once I take out the `open: function () { ... }` bit and I can reopen the modal again and again but once I put this back in the error gets thrown. This is obviously the cause but cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for the very long post.

UPDATE:

I've attempted initializing the modal in document.ready and call it from my "drop" function in the first main function. From doing this I've narrowed it down to this line of code which loads the partial view from my controller. Without this line the functionality works. Any ideas on what is wrong with this.

```
$(this).load("AdditionalContent", { itemName: itemName }
```

Comment: @Mark OB: I would create the dialog once and repopulate the contents (using `.load`) outside of the `open` function. I've seen weird things happen when widgets get called multiple times on an element. Have you tried a strategy like that?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: I tried something similar to this initializing the modal in the $(document).ready. I didn't try to populate the contents outside of the open function. Will give it a try when I get home and let you know. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @MarkOB: Saw the update--Have you seen the result come back in an inspection tool like Firebug? Could you be getting a server error? For example, is it possible that MVC is not finding the partial view?

Comment: Try changing `{ itemName: itemName }` to `{ "itemName": itemName }` and see if it has something to do with the name of your key and variable being the same.

Comment: Also, to fix the issue with subsequent calls to this function, at the top of your function, add: `$('#dialogs').dialog('destroy');`

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: MVC is defiantly finding the partial view because it loads it the first time round. Its on either pressing the "Close" button or trying to drag a new item that I get the error which is $(this).dialog is not a function. The fact that it works once and then breaks is the annoying bit

Comment: @Mark OB: Agreed with @Jim, what happens when you add that line?

Comment: I use partial view results for jQuery dialogs in MVC 3, and I don't have the same issue with views being cached.  I do, however, have the buttons specified in the partial view, so I'm not using the dialog's buttons.  In the load callback, I then bind click handlers to the buttons in my view.  For instance, a cancel button's callback will be `function(){ $('#dialog').dialog('close'); }`

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: Same issue when using Jim's { "itemName" : itemName }, even tried to change the variable.

Comment: @Jim: I tried the .destroy method but then the popup does not open at all. I included at the top of the second function which now looks like this - function getItemType(thisItem) {
            $('#dialogs').dialog('destroy');
            $('#dialogs').dialog('open');
            $('#dialogs').load("AdditionalContent", { "itemName":   thisItem });
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Included in the partial views was a second call to the jQuery library which was added automatically when the view was created. Plus it was version 1.4.4 while I was using 1.5.1 straight from Google in the _Layout page. The second jQuery library was obviously breaking the functionality as there was a conflict between the two versions. It wasn't until I watched the FireBug console that I noticed the second loading of the 1.4.4 library.

Thanks to all for your help, feel like a bit of an idiot but lesson learned..... for now

Answer (score -2):

could try this but i am not sure

```
$('#dialogs').dialog({
     var self = this;
            open: function () {
                $(self).load("AdditionalContent", { itemName: itemName }, function () {
                    alert("This happened");
                });
            },
```

Comment: This will not work. You can't declare a variable like that inside of an object literal.

Comment: I see where you are going with this but the error still presents itself even by using the actual name of the DIV as in $('#dialogs').load